# docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy in docker container using Jenkins on windows but my build failed with following errors.

1>' docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
2>Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

```
docker build -t reactapp . 
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 --name "recipes" reactapp
```

Comment: You have to install Docker. If it is installed be sure that the path is included in the environment variable.

Comment: mmm what if i do have it on the path environment variable? does the order on the path variable matters?

Answer (score 3):

> ' docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

This errors means that you dont have docker in your PATH environment variable.

You need to look for the docker.exe location, I did a default installation and I have it in : `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`
and add it to your path environment variable.

[How to Add to Windows PATH Environment Variable](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)